# How to set output to a specific channel in AudioKit?

Tags: ios, macos, audiokit

I'm currently working with AudioKit and there is one issue for which I would need some help.

I have 4 track files which are defined as `AKPlayer`.

```
var drums = AKPlayer(audioFile: drumsFile)
var bass = AKPlayer(audioFile: bassFile)
var guitar = AKPlayer(audioFile: guitarFile)
var lead = AKPlayer(audioFile: leadFile)
```

Also, I have an external output device with 8 channels and I would like to put drums to channel 1, bass to channel 2 and guitar with lead to channel 3.

Is there any possibility to do that? In this case, those need to be set as mono. When they are set to stereo, then drums should be on channel 1-2, bass on 3-4 and guitar with lead on 5-6.

Am I doing this right or is there any other approach?

Comment: As of right AudioKit is mostly designed for stereo, ie. 2 channel output. We're hoping to alleviate this limitation in a future version this year.